# can someone please clarify my doubts on pivot table in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pivot

In a input table, the key and value are columns names. Below is input table and I want below table in this o/p format but the data is not
coming ... when we can `%` symbol in the square brackets with out using
pivot in the query then data is displaying.but same I'm using in pivot
it is displaying blanks. Help me how to use `%` symbol and like operator
in pivot query thanks in advance.

input table:

```
key      value 
-------------------
sal[0]    2000 
sal[1]    3000 
sal[2]    1000 
emp[0]    10 
emp[1]    20 
emp[2]    30 
ename[0]  rag 
ename[1]  swa 
ename[2]  yag
```

output format:

```
  emp   ename sal
  ---------------- 
  10    rag   2000 
  20    swa   3000 
  30    yag   1000
```

My query is:

```sql
 SELECT * 
   FROM INPUT 
 PIVOT (
    MAX (VALUE) FOR KEY IN ('EMP[%]' AS EMP,
                            'ENAME[%]' AS ENAME,
                            'SAL[%]' AS SAL
                            )
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Values listed in the `IN` clause of the `PIVOT` clause are expected to be constant values
of a pivot column. While percent sign in the `LIKE` condition is considered to be a
wildcard, in the `IN`clause of the `PIVOT` clause it is just a literal.

As one of the options, we can get rid of those square brackets(unless they are carrying
some special value) using [regexp_substr()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions150.htm#i1239858) regular expression function and then do the pivot:

```
SQL> with t1(key1, value1) as(
  2    select 'sal[0]'  ,  '2000'  from dual union all
  3    select 'sal[1]'  ,  '3000'  from dual union all
  4    select 'sal[2]'  ,  '1000'  from dual union all
  5    select 'emp[0]'  ,  '10'    from dual union all
  6    select 'emp[1]'  ,  '20'    from dual union all
  7    select 'emp[2]'  ,  '30'    from dual union all
  8    select 'ename[0]',  'rag'   from dual union all
  9    select 'ename[1]',  'swa'   from dual union all
 10    select 'ename[2]',  'yag'   from dual
 11  )
 12  select emp
 13       , sal
 14       , ename
 15    from ( select regexp_substr(key1, '^[[:alpha:]]+') as key1
 16                , value1
 17                , row_number() over(partition by regexp_substr(key1, '^[[:alpha:]]+') order by value1)
 18             from t1
 19          )
 20  pivot(
 21    max(value1) for  key1 in ('emp' as emp, 'sal' as sal, 'ename' as ename)
 22  )
 23  ;
```

Result:

```
EMP  SAL   ENAME
---- ----  -----
10   1000  rag
20   2000  swa
30   3000  yag
```

Comment: key      value 
-------------------
sal[0]    2000 
sal[1]    3000 
sal[2]    1000 
emp[0]    10 
emp[1]    20 
emp[2]    30 
ename[0]  rag 
ename[1]  swa 
ename[2]  yag